# onclick button save data in db php

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to update a field in db as 1 or 0 when i click on yes or no button..

```
<table id="main" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Approve</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <?php $i = 0; foreach($purchaseorder as $tdata): $i++;  ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $tdata['pay_date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tdata['amount']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" onClick="save(this);" value="Yes">
                <input type="button" onClick="save(this);" value="No">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <script>
            function save(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Marketing/add.ctp",
                    data: {title: title},
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert("Ajax save executed!");
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Above code displays the button in view page as yes and no. 
When i click on yes button there is no change in database.
What should i do??

Comment: what does `Marketing/add.ctp` contain? Also you have no variable declared...

Comment: data: {title: title}, which variable have you pass in ajax

Comment: you can write ` <input type="button" onClick="save("no");" value="No">` instead of `"save(this)`

Answer (score 2):

Take the value of the button and send it through AJAX request like this.

```
<table id="main" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Approve</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php $i= 0;
    foreach($purchaseorder as $tdata): $i++; ?>
    <tr >
        <td><?php echo $tdata['pay_date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tdata['amount']; ?></td>
        <td>  <input type="button" onClick="save(this);" value="Yes">
        <input type="button" onClick="save(this);" value="No"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
function save(curEle){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Marketing/add.ctp",
    data: {status: curEle.value},
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Ajax save executed!");
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

In your PHP script save the status as 1 for 'yes' and 0 for 'no'

Comment: Need more information than just not working!